# Python form with ajax generates KeyError

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, forms

I have a Python controller file, a form, and a javascript file that executes ajax code upon the submit button being clicked on the form.  The form gets displayed correctly. When I enter data into the form, the ajax code triggers and executes the code in the class PostRegistration which resides in the controller.py file.  When the code is executed, I print "inside class PostRegistration" to the console, then I retrieve the form data through the use of the code data = web.input().  When I print the contents of data to the console, I get "data= ". I was hoping to see form names and values.  I then execute a line of code which says print(data.username) but this generates "KeyError: 'username'".  My assumption is that the form field names are not being retrieved by the web.input() command but I'm not sure. How can I retrieve the data entered into the form input elements?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here are the files that are involved:

controller.py

```
import web
from Models import RegisterModel

urls = (

    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration'
)

render = web.template.render("views/templates", base="MainLayout")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

# Classes/Routes

class Home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.home()

class Register:
    def GET(self):
        return render.register()

class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        print("inside class PostRegistration")
        data = web.input()
        print("data=",data)
        print(data.username)
        return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

register.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Register Account</h2>
    <br /><br />

    <form id="register-form">

        <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
            <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
            <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Choose a username" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
            <label for="fullname" class="control-label">Full Name</label>
            <input id="fullname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">eMail</label>
            <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
            <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
            <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect ripple">Submit </button>

    </form>

</div>
```

scripty.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("loaded");

    $(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#register-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/postregistration",
            type: "POST",
            data: form,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

mainlayout.html

```
$def with (page)

$var css: static/css/bootstrap3.3.7.css static/css/material.css static/css/ripple.min.css
$var js: static/js/jquery-3.2.1.js static/js/bootstrap3.3.7.js static/js/material.js static/js/ripple.min.js static/js/scripty.js

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodeWizard</title>

    $if self.css:
        $for style in self.css.split():
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="$style" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="navbar navbar-info navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">CodeWizard</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="waves-effect" href="/">Home Feed<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="waves-effect" href="/discover">Discover<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="waves-effect" href="/profile">Profile<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="waves-effect" href="/settings">Settings<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="/register" class="btn btn-raised btn-default waves-effect">Register</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        $:page
    </div>

    $if self.js:
        $for script in self.js.split():
            <script src="$script"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of your input elements have `name` attributes, so there is nothing for jQuery to serialize.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  Moving from 1 language to another, sometimes the most obvious things are the things most often overlooked.